# Ansible synchronize hangs when executing inside ssh with delegate_to

Tags: ssh, rsync, ansible

The following task works fine when run directly from my machine.
When I run it from a remote machine through SSH it hangs forever.

This is the task:

```
  - name: deploy public directory
    synchronize: src="{{ my_root_path }}/.deploy/office/public/" dest="{{ my_root_path}}/office/public/" compress=no checksum=yes delete=yes recursive=yes times=yes links=yes archive=no rsync_opts=--no-motd,--exclude=.gitignore
    delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

This is the output before it hangs:

```
<88.81.184.149> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<88.81.184.149> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/root/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 88.81.184.149 /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1440505364.9-19277754718304 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1440505364.9-19277754718304'
<88.81.184.149> PUT /tmp/tmpr44yYm TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1440505364.9-19277754718304/synchronize
<88.81.184.149> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/root/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 88.81.184.149 /bin/sh -c 'LANG=C LC_CTYPE=C /usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1440505364.9-19277754718304/synchronize; rm -rf /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1440505364.9-19277754718304/ >/dev/null 2>&1'
```

Any ideas of what might be going wrong?

Comment: as far as I know synchronize underneath does just local shell: rsync... so this should not work but I've heard some users add this to sync options and get it done: "rsync_opts='--rsh "ssh -i /root/.ssh/ansible"'' - so try this or just use "shell" to make comand run on remote host.

Answer (score 4):

After some investigation, the issue turned out to be related to agent forwarding.
Adding `-o ForwardAgent = yes` to the `ssh_args` setting in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` did the trick.

Comment: Thanks very much, I solved the problem with your solution.  [ssh_connection]\nssh_args= -o ForwardAgent=yes