# Ansible hangs when copying from a remote host to remote hosts

Tags: ssh, ansible

I wanted to copy a file generated on hostA to production severs and tried the task below but Ansible hangs. I set `ssh_args=-i ForwardAgent=yes` as is suggested in the [previous post](https://serverfault.com/questions/716605/ansible-synchronize-hangs-when-executing-inside-ssh-with-delegate-to) but this has not effect. What is the problem here?

```
- name: Copy certificate from hostA to production servers                     
  synchronize:                                                   
    mode: pull                                             
    src: /etc/td-agent/ca_cert.pem
    dest: /etc/td-agent/ca_cert.pem                               
  delegate_to: "{{item}}"
  with_items: groups.production
```

UPDATE: the log is as follows:

```
TASK: [td-agent | Copy certificate to sender]       
<192.168.50.3> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: foo
<192.168.50.3> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ForwardAgent=yes -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=foo -o ConnectTimeout=10 192.168.50.3 /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441765316.04-268038164469731 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441765316.04-268038164469731 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441765316.04-268038164469731'
<192.168.50.3> PUT /tmp/user/1000/tmpocwPOc TO /home/foo/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441765316.04-268038164469731/synchronize
<192.168.50.3> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ForwardAgent=yes -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=foo -o ConnectTimeout=10 192.168.50.3 /bin/sh -c 'sudo -k && sudo -H -S -p "[sudo via ansible, key=wklthazqaiqrywuyoafjdpxwmqrpklyt] password: " -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-wklthazqaiqrywuyoafjdpxwmqrpklyt; LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /home/kuma/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441765316.04-268038164469731/synchronize; rm -rf /home/foo/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441765316.04-268038164469731/ >/dev/null 2>&1'"'"''
```

Comment: Can you post verbose output? Have you considered using `copy` module instead of `synchronize`?

Comment: I think you need to use `synchronize` module to make use of the `delegate_to` option. First guess: `rsync` binary is not installed on the delegated host. you should activate verbose output with `-vvvv` as suggested.

Comment: @Mxx Is it possible to copy a file from remote to remote with `copy`?

Comment: @knowhy I checked rsync is installed on the delegated host.

Comment: maybe it is a [bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/10906). Or maybe you need to set `set_remote_user: false` parameter.

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be `-o`?